# Why does the CSS border of an iframe flicker and how to fix it?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, iframe, safari

I have an iframe border using CSS. As the page is resized the border sometimes disappears in Chrome and changes size in Safari (it's fine in Firefox)

[image]

Is there a known workaround?

```js
const html = `
<style>
body { 
  background: #DDD;
}
</style>
<body>
  <div>hello iframe</div>
</body>
`;

const blob = new Blob([html], {type: 'text/html'});
document.querySelector("iframe").src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

```css
div {
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
iframe {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Size the window and watch the right border</p>
<!-- src set from JavaScript because offsite iframes are often banned -->
<div>
  <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

Using other elements don't have the same issue

```css
div {
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
span, canvas {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<p>no issue with other elements</p>
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

note that it seems to have something to do with having a background color in the iframe. If I remove the background color the problem goes away in Chrome (though not Safari)

```js
const html = `
<body>
  <div>hello iframe</div>
</body>
`;

const blob = new Blob([html], {type: 'text/html'});
document.querySelector("iframe").src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

```css
div {
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
iframe {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Size the window and watch the right border</p>
<!-- src set from JavaScript because offsite iframes are often banned -->
<div>
  <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Filed a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=765138). Still looking for a workaround

Answer (score 2):

I still see the issue on Chrome (not on Safari). It seems like a bug in visualization of the border (still).

One option could be to change the `border` to have a width of 0 and set an `outline` instead. Then this effect goes away. I don't know if it would be the best solution (outlines are used often to highlight focused/active elements), but it would be close to what you have.

Here is a demo just with that change:

```js
const html = `
<style>
body { 
  background: #eee;
}
</style>
<body>
  <div>hello iframe</div>
</body>
`;

const blob = new Blob([html], {type: 'text/html'});
document.querySelector("iframe").src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

```css
div {
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
iframe {
  display: block;
  border: 0;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Size the window and watch the right border</p>
<!-- src set from JavaScript because offsite iframes are often banned -->
<div>
  <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work for me. `outline` has the same issue. https://imgur.com/a/sM9uvdc  Though I see it works for the code I posted above. I wonder what's different from my actual sitation.

Comment: Also if I set the background of iframe to red and the iframe's content body to gray you'll see this didn't quite work. https://imgur.com/a/sM9uvdc

Answer (score 1):

Adding a wrapper div with `overflow: hidden;` and `box-sizing: border-box;` works for me.

```js
const html = `
<style>
body { 
  background: #eee;
}
</style>
<body>
  <div>hello iframe</div>
</body>
`;

const blob = new Blob([html], {type: 'text/html'});
document.querySelector("iframe").src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

```css
div {
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.iframe-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
iframe {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Size the window and watch the right border</p>
<!-- src set from JavaScript because offsite iframes are often banned -->
<div>
  <div class="iframe-wrapper">
     <iframe></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I set the background of iframe to red and the iframe's content body to gray you'll see this didn't quite work. https://imgur.com/a/sM9uvdc

Answer (score 0):

This is an antialiasing issue.
Chrome generally avoids rendering on floating pixels, to avoid antialiasing. It will try to move and resize to the next rounded pixels.
In this case, it will cut off your border instead of making it leak outside of the iframe.

You can force it by either moving or resizing your iframe by floating-pixels:

```js
const html = `
<style>
body { 
  background: #DDD;
}
</style>
<body>
  <div>hello iframe</div>
</body>
`;
const iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
iframe.srcdoc = html;

document.querySelector("input").oninput = function(e) {
  iframe.style.marginLeft = this.value + 'px';
};
```

```css
div {
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
iframe {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 250.5px; /* force a floating pixel width */
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Edit the range and watch the right border</p>
<input type="range" min="0" max="1" value="0" step="0.01">
<!-- src set from JavaScript because offsite iframes are often banned -->
<div>
  <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

I think you did good opening this issue, since it's definitely not the expected behavior.

And since you asked for a workaround, here is one, far from being perfect, which will cause double reflows at each resize event, but which should fix the bug...

```js
const html = `
<style>
body { 
  background: #DDD;
}
</style>
<body>
  <div>hello iframe</div>
</body>
`;
const iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
iframe.srcdoc = html;

addEventListener('resize', resizeFrame, {passive: true});
resizeFrame();

function resizeFrame(_){
  iframe.style.width = null; // reset to 100%
  // force reflow by calling offsetWidth which is already rounded
  iframe.style.width = iframe.offsetWidth + 'px'; 
}
```

```css
div {
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
iframe {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Size the window and watch the right border</p>
<!-- src set from JavaScript because offsite iframes are often banned -->
<div>
  <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

But note that this code only takes care of resize events, if your iframe can resize from other events (e.g DOM manips, CSS etc.) then you might want to use a wrapper element on which you'd apply the `width:100%` and from a ResizeObserver's callback change your iframe's width:

```js
const html = `
<style>
body { 
  background: #DDD;
}
</style>
<body>
  <div>hello iframe</div>
</body>
`;
const iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
iframe.srcdoc = html;

if(window.ResizeObserver) {
  const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
    iframe.style.width = iframe.parentNode.offsetWidth + 'px';
  });
  observer.observe(iframe.parentNode);
}
else {
  console.log('no support');
}
```

```css
div {
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
iframe {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
.iframe-wrapper {
  max-width: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Size the window and watch the right border</p>
<!-- src set from JavaScript because offsite iframes are often banned -->
<div>
<div class="iframe-wrapper">
  <iframe></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

That is, [in Blink only for now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver#Browser_compatibility)...

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me. What did work was just setting the iframe width and height to a fixed amount, instead of a percentage:

instead of:

```
a iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #9af4b4;
}
```

changed it to this, because the iframe was inside a fixed widht container anyway:

```
a iframe {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #9af4b4;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.ifrmoutr{
  border: 1px solid red;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.ifrmoutr iframe{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="ifrmoutr">
      <iframe></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

For anyone looking for an answer to this in 2022 and none of the above works, this is the only thing that worked for me.

Add the following CSS to the `iframe`:

```
clip-path: polygon(1% 1%, 99% 1%, 99% 99%, 1% 99%);
```

Comment: this made the border disappear